# 301 Redirect in htaccess from directory level to back

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect

```
domain.com/category/amp/
domain.com/category/subcategory/amp/
```

to

```
domain.com/category/
domain.com/category/subcategory/
```

Due to facing some issues, i removed amp from my website. But now all these amp pages showing as 404 errors.

How to redirect all amp pages to related page using htaccess.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(.+)/amp(/.*)?$ /$1$2
```

This will 301 redirect **/foo/amp** to **/foo** and **/foo/amp/bar** to **/foo/bar**

Answer (score 0):

```
#Redirect old path to new path
Redirect /category/amp/ http://example.com/category/
Redirect /category/subcategory/amp/ http://example.com/category/subcategory/
```